# An IFTTT recipe to post every link I post to a sub-reddit into a Quora Board?

Tags: reddit, if-this-then-that, quora

Does anyone know how to use [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) in order to take every post on a specific sub-reddit (not comments, just "top level" posts), and import them into a specific [Quora Board](https://www.quora.com/Boards-on-Quora/What-are-Quora-boards)?

Comment: Mods: The Quora boards feature is discontinued, see my answer to the post for more details

Answer (score 1):

**It's not possible.**

1. [IFTTT doesn't support quora](https://ifttt.com/search/query/quora) (but it does support acting on a trigger for a new post in sub-reddit).
2. It seems that Quora boards are discontinued:

   - Links such as you shared that are under `Boards-on-Quora` now redirects to `Boards-discontinued-Quora-feature`.
   - https://www.quora.com/topic/Boards-discontinued-Quora-feature 
     [image]